# Laravel 5 Dependent Dropdown List Approach

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, drop-down-menu

I'm new to Laravel 5 but I've already tried Laravel 4. Can someone give me advise to this situation, I have a registration page, so I just used Laravel's built-in registration module /auth/register/. Problem is I added a few dropdown list in the form which is State, Regions, Area, City.

The list of values that Regions will have depends on the selected State, then list values of Area depends on selected value for Regions, last is list values of Cities depends on selected value of Area.

I could have done this using javascript but when it comes to frameworks, how can I do this? Suppose I will put my javascript on the register view, how about the database query for Regions, Area and City? Where should I call the query from this models? I bet you'll say I call the query on the controller then pass it as a parameter as it renders the view but in Laravel 5, the rendering of register page is located at

C:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php

with the code:

```
public function getRegister()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}
```

But It doesn't let me do this:

```
public function getRegister()
{
    $regions = with(new Regions)->getRegions(); 
    return view('auth.register')->with('regions', $regions);
}
```

If I access the $regions variable on my view it will say undefined.
So how can I do this? or what is a better approach? Thanks

Comment: Use ajax request. Define the route and use `list` to generate the `html`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like below, which gives your array of regions you can use in Form::select items list. If you see that the $regions is empty in the view then you can try debugging with dd($regions) or with `dd(view('auth.register')->with('regions', $regions))` . These dd() calls will show if the values are correct and $regions is set.

btw if Regions is a Model then convention says you should use singular form, Region instead of Regions

```
public function getRegister()
{
    $regions = Region::lists("name", "id"); 
    return view('auth.register')->with('regions', $regions);
}
```